# SQL MERGE Statement with More Than 2 Tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, merge

```
Table 1
Id Name Address


Table 2
Id Company Salary

Table3
Id Name Address Company Salary Age Sex
```

> I want to Merge These table in a single MERGE statement, Is This
>   Possible??

Like

```
MERGE table1 AS tg1
MERGE table2 AS tg2
USING (SELECT Id ,Name ,Address FROM Table3) AS sr
ON tg1.Id = sr.Id and tg2.Id = sr.Id
WHEN MATCHED (tg1.Id =sr.Id) then DELETE
WHEN MATCHED (tg2.Id =sr.Id) then UPDATE SET tg2.Company = 'MyCompany'+sr.Company
and so on..
```

> Is there any other Keyword i need to use for this type of `MERGE`
>   Statement, or i need to `use` two different `MERGE` Statement for
>   this.

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: @tinka: Thanks for the link, but nothing related to my question.i'm asking `in a single merge statement,is is possible to merge with more than 2 table`?

Comment: [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) can has only one Target table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) can have only one target table.

But you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Id INT);

MERGE table2 AS tg2
USING (SELECT Id, Name, Address, Company FROM Table3) AS sr
ON and tg2.Id = sr.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET tg2.Company = 'MyCompany' + sr.Company
OUTPUT tg2.Id INTO @T;

DELETE table1
WHERE Id in (SELECT Id
                 FROM @T);
```

OUTPUT can also return *$action* so you can differentiate DELETE/INSERT/UPDATE if needed. 
You can even use CTE before MERGE and prepare your source table to avoid complex conditions in MERGE.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two MERGE statements. One to change the data in table1, and one to change the data in table2.